# Удалить файл на другом поддомене

Tags: php

Нужно удалить файл на другом поддомене на одном сервере. То есть php-скрипт удаления вызывается на одном поддомене (dom1.site.ru), а файл находится на другом.

Следующая штука с указанием полного серверского пути не помогла:

```
unlink("/var/www/user/data/www/dom2.site.ru/img/1.jpg");
```

Как быть?

Comment: А эти сайты находятся на одной физической машине?

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я написал.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдал unlink?

Может, просто прав недостаточно, или для сайта chroot используется, и он выше своего корня ничего не видит...

Comment: @Sergiks, тоесть, можно удалить только запустив пхп на том же сайте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-разному, бывает, настраивают сервер.

Как вариант, ещё можно попробовать указать относительный путь от скрипта: `../../dom2.site.ru/img/1.jpg`

Но это всё догадки.

**Обновление**

Можно только гадать:

1. Для сайтов php запускается с `chroot` и поэтому вылезти за его пределы невозможно.
2. php запускается под разными пользователями для каждого поддомена, и поэтому нет разрешения на модификацию/удаление того файла.

Костыль: сделать на втором сайте скрипт, который будет удалять файл «у себя», и дёргать его через HTTP. Подумайте над безопасностью: проверяйте, чтобы только с этого же ip можно было его звать.

Comment: @Sergiks, как ни странно, сработало. ) Я по глупости писал в начале `.../dom2.site.ru/img/1.jpg`, не сталкивался просто с переходом в каталог выше.